# Gradle eclipse classpath - Switching between SNAPSHOT and project dependency

Tags: eclipse, gradle

We have a multiple modules in our Java project and each module publishes SNAPSHOT jar files to Nexus repository. All the sub-modules are directly dependent on the SNAPSHOT jar files.

During development, we want to depend on the Eclipse project rather than SNAPSHOT jars. So we introduced a flag which switches between the dependencies as shown below.

```
if(System.properties.'setupProject'){
    compile project(':Core')
    compile project(':Module1')
    compile project(':Module2')
}else{
    compile 'com.test:core:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.test:module1:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.test:module2:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

Executing the following command generates the .classpath file as expected.

> gradle eclipse -DsetupProject=true

Is there a better way to do this? Can we use Gradle configurations to achieve the same?
I could not find good examples for the same.

Comment: Are there any changes on this issue?

Comment: No. We went with this approach. I have accepted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this is the way to go. You might tweak this even more and instead of using a System property to mark a project as available you can check if the project folder is available (project is checked out)

cheers,
René

Comment: Are the now other solutions available?

Comment: Well, a more automatic way, similar to what M2E does for maven: If a the project is present in eclipse, use it as reference, otherwise use the jar from the repo. Just as the original question author described.

Comment: So you're talking about IDE integration. That is something the IDE must provide. The Gradle plugin for eclipse was originated by the springsource guys. You find more information about that at https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-gradle The feature request you describe here is already listed in their issue tracker at https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2834 At the moment there is one gradle issue blocking them from implementing this. can you place your vote at http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2750