# How do I use a local gradle project as a dependency for another local gradle project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

This worked fine using Maven. Project A would depend on Project B and when I loaded up both Project A and Project B then Project A would use the locally built jar for Project B instead of depending on the jar pulled from Nexus.

All my projects use Gradle now and I can't figure out how to get them to see each other.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487145/gradle-eclipse-classpath-switching-between-snapshot-and-project-dependency?rq=1.

Answer (score 2):

If it is just a simple Eclipse Project A depends on Project B, then this simple solution is what worked for me (I had to read for so long to figure this out! Why wasn't it obvious?)

- **Project B** is its own Gradle project and is not necessarily aware of other projects - you don't have to do anything special for Project B
- **Project A**:
- settings.gradle

  ```
  include 'Project B'

  project (':Project B').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, "../Project B")
  ```
- build.gradle

  ```
  dependencies {
      compile project (':Project B')
  }
  ```

Save the two, and do an Eclipse -> Gradle -> Refresh Dependencies, and you will now see Project B as an actual Project Dependency in the Gradle Dependencies of Project A (I had to use dashes instead of spaces since Eclipse wouldn't let me have spaces in my Gradle projects' names).
[image: Eclipse Gradle Project Dependencies]

Note: if building these projects on a remote server, make sure that you are either checking these two projects into the same source control repository or make sure that they end up in the same place relative to each other the way they are in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the Gradle User Guide, at Chapter 51, "Dependency Management".  See if section 51.4.3, "Project dependencies" does what you need.